# Multiple share buttons on one page

Tags: facebook, twitter, sharing

I have a liveblog with multiple articles on it. I want to add a fb and twitter share button to each article.. how do I do this? I can't link to the page because then there's no real link to the article on that specific page. Ideally I would like to include an image, title and description for fb sharing...

Example page: http://vygo.be/livepagina-jumping-antwerpen-2014/